# Issue: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Real screen element corresponding to shadow element ElementDescription

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in Google Play. In my last build Google showed me this issue:

> **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:** Real screen element corresponding to shadow element `ElementDescription{className=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView, resourceName=com.myappp.testapp:id/lab_separator, contentDescription=, componentType=TEXT_VIEW, inputType=NONE, isWebViewElement=false}` not found.

I could not resolve this issue in the app. The view mentioned in the report works ok. Everything works as expected but I want to fix what was reported by Google.

Comment: I had the same thing pop up on my pre-launch reports in the past few days. Similar recent reports on github. I think it's a Google bug in their app crawler. Currently have a tech support ticket open with them.

Comment: Same problem here, I submitted a question to their support almost a week ago and no response. Also submitted the same APK with the only difference being the version code and got different results.

Comment: Do you have alternative layouts(e.g., layout and layout-large). So one layout has TextView with id=lab_separator and the alternative one doesn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a member of the crawler team, I can confirm that this was a result of a regression in the crawler. The fix for this will be deployed in a day or two. Thank you for using Robo and reporting issues with it!

Comment: Is this already fixed? I got this error on a just uploaded version today.